# How to get the recaptcha value using multiple recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recaptcha

I am using the `google recaptcha`. I am rendering it by using `explicity` method[provided by google].

In the previous version there was `only one recaptcha`. In the new version we used `multiple recaptcha` for different forms on the same page. In the previous version I was getting the value of recaptcha by

```
$("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
```

Now since there are `multiple recaptcha`, I am not able to get the value. How can I get the value of recaptcha of that particular form.

Comment: Show the HTML you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same id property on single page multiple times. You can add a generic class to all of the elements having id `g-recaptcha-response` and then try following code.

```
$(".yourClassName").each(function(){
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(currentVal);
});
```